# I have a list defined as "line" and I want to substitute it into my code

Tags: python, list, variables

So i have a list of values defined as "line". Instead of putting that large list into my code I want to instead enter "line" to make my code shorter.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from bioservices import UniProt
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
u = UniProt(verbose=False)
d = u.search("id: (line))", frmt="tab",
             columns="id,protein names,organism,go(molecular function),go(biological process),go(cellular component),sequence")
```

Here I simply put it in a parenthesis so the elements of that list can be used as the "id:" in my search but it doesn't seem to recognize it as the list that I defined as "line" and instead is just blank

Comment: I don't see where you define a `line` variable.

Comment: Try an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/): `u.search(f"id: {line}", ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you did not define `list`. Its not printing anything because the variable `list` is blank. Second of all, you have to change the format of code in line 6. It should be `d = u.search(f"id: {line}", frmt = "tab",`.